# How to get recent places in terminal/shell?

Tags: shell, zsh, command-history, cd-command

Is there any way to get a list of the most recent 'places' (directories) that have been navigated in terminal (osx)? I mean, I'd like to open my terminal, type some command, get the last 2 or 3 places I've been, and go there.

Something like what the arrows do for recent commands.

Is it possible?

Comment: Use your shell's command line history feature and search for `cd` commands? `Ctrl+R` in some shells.

Comment: Mmm thank you but not exactly what I intended

Comment: Well, that (using the shell's history) was literally what you suggested yourself when you mentioned the arrow keys. You could also manage a set of symbolic links to directories to which you often go. The shell is not quite like a web browser, it does not have a "bookmark" facility. You may possibly find something like that in a file manager though.

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` might be what you are looking for.  Instead of using `cd`, try using `pushd`.  That `cd`s to that directory, but saves the previous directory on the stack.  When you `popd`, you go back to the previous directory.  Stephane's answer is good if you already know that `pushd` and `popd` exist but want to simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your shell is `zsh` (which AFAIK is the default in newer versions of macos), you can set the `autopushd` option (`set -o autopushd` in your `~/.zshrc`) which will cause `zsh` to remember all the places (current working directories, changed with `cd`/`pushd`/`popd`) you've been.

Then, you can see that stack with:

```
dirs
```

Or `dirs -v`, so see the index of each directory on the stack, which you can use for instance in `cd +5`, or `ls -ld ~+5` for the 5th entry (passed the top line which is the current directory in `dirs`'s output).

or:

```
print -rC1 $dirstack
```

(`$dirstack` exposing that stack in an array, without the current working directory).

Or, if you're enabled advanced completion with descriptions (see `compinstall`) with the completion list on:

```
cd +<Tab>
```

or

```
cd -<Tab>
```

Or for any command after the `~-` or `~+`:

```
any cmd ~+<Tab>
```

For example, with

```
set -o autopushd
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit -i
```

in `~/.zshrc`, after I've visited a few directories, upon pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, I get a menu such as:

```
% cd +1
Completing directory stack
[1 -- ~/Videos]
 2 -- ~/Downloads
 3 -- ~/
 4 -- /usr
 5 -- /tmp
```

Which I can navigate with the arrow keys.

The directory stack feature itself is not zsh-specific. It and the `pushd` / `popd` / `dirs` commands to manipulate it were introduced by `csh` in 1980, copied by `bash` (1.02 in 1989) and `zsh` (1.0 in 1990) later. The `cd +5`, `cd -5` also come from `csh` (added to zsh in 2.0 in 1991). `~+` / `~-` are from `bash` (1989) copied later by `zsh` (1991) while `~+5` is from `zsh` (1996), copied later by `bash` (1997). Only `autopushd` (for `cd` to also use that stack, like a silent `pushd`) is `zsh`-specific, and its completion framework is far ahead that of `bash` and now also `tcsh` (but is being caught up by that of `fish`).